# Create a method to change Button effects in c#

Tags: c#

I want to animate buttons in c#. So i  create a method called HoverMouseBut() as follows.

```
public void HoverMouseBut(Button name,Image img, int w, int h)
{
    name.Image = Resources.img;
    name.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(232, 126, 4);
    name.Size = new Size(w, h);
    name.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
    name.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
    name.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
}
```

I called this method as follows;

```
private void addo_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HoverMouseBut(addo,Add2,250,160);

}
```

This gave me a syntax error. I changed the method without image parameter and see.Then it worked.But  I want to change the image of the button as well.How could I do this? Whats wrong with my code?

*Add2 is an image in resources .

Comment: Looks like you're always setting the `Button.Image` property to `Resources.img` - perhaps you should just be setting it to the `img` parameter: `name.Image = img;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using C# and forms are like other properties in C#. Therefore you have different options to do that. 
One of the easiest ones is to have a public property of your needed type in your second form and use that to pass data

```
class Form2
{
 public string myStringField{get;set;}
}

class Form1
{
 myMethod()
 {
 ....
 var newForm= new Form2();
 newForm.myStringField="Something";
 }
}
```

However, if your Form2 can not exist without your field, it make sense to put your filed in the constructor

```
class Form2
{
  public Form2 (string myStringField)
 {...}
}
class Form1
{
 myMethod()
 {
 ....
 var newForm= new Form2("Something");

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to pass an Image to the method for use, why did you set `name.Image = Resources.img` ?

Changing it to `name.Image = img` might work